# Error: Failed to connect to remote target after update to 4.0.0.2

Tags: samsung-mobile, watch, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I updated my gear sport several days ago. After updating to 4.0.0.2, I cannot connect to my watch anymore. Here is my command:

```
./sdb connect [IP]
```

It aways said:

```
error: failed to connect to remote target [IP]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Turn on Developer mode by tapping several time on the software version number.

Comment: sure, and I also toggle the debug mode "ON". Are you still using 4.0.0.2 on Gear Sport?

Comment: I am not saying about debug mode....i am saying about Developer mode by tapping on software version number

Comment: Yes, I indeed tapping on software version number and see the developer option in the settings. Are you sure you are using Gear sport 4.0.0.2, and you can connect to your watch?

Comment: Yes..try with different PC

Comment: It works when I change to the Windows PC. After, I use the Mac and it can connect to my Gear Sport again. It is so weird, and I don't why it happened.

Comment: Enabling the Developer option is the solution

Answer (score 8):

On the device, go to `Settings` -> `About watch` -> `Software`, from there, tap repeatedly on `Software version` until `Developer Mode` is enabled. *Then* restart your device, and try to connect.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm the successful steps, it has to be ALL of those steps, and then restart the watch.

Bluetooth: Off, Wifi: On, Debugging: On, Developer Mode: On. Then restart watch.

It will connect after ALL of those settings are in those EXACT states.
No other combination worked, not even after a watch restart, additionally my pc is connect to the router via cat5 cable, but the watch is connected over wifi.

Windows 10, Tizen Studio 3.6 (2019-11-22), Galaxy Watch Active 2 (Tizen 4.0.0.7, One UI 1.5)

Comment: restarting worked thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:
turn off BT
Restart Watch (OFF and ON)
Connect via Wifi with device manager.

Comment: It does not work for me. I try to use my phone as a hotspot and connect both my phone and computer to it. Then, it works again.

Comment: Important is, that you reboot watch after turning off BT nad turning NO wiFi

Comment: Restarting the watch after enabling developer mode worked. I can now ping the watch, as well as connect in the device manager. I have a Frontier S3, running Tizen 4.0.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I finally got my galaxy watch connected. Here are the config/status my watch had:
Developer mode:on,
Bluetooth:off,
Debugging:on,
Wifi:connected to my phone's AP,
laptop:connected to my phone's AP

After connecting both devices to the same AP, i was able to find and connect to my galaxy watch on tizen studio. So, connecting with a phone's AP worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept debugging rha fingerprint from your watch. That is, you need to check and press the tick on the watch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).